# Magento 2 : how to configure multiple domain in nginx server

Tags: magento2

i have create multiple store view for access the same site using below domain example.

```
dev.com ( main site )
created two store view for uk and aus.
dev.uk
dev.aus
```

right now, my domain is not point so i can access this aus and uk website 
using below url

```
dev.com/uk
dev.com/aus
```

for that i have create two folder in pub/aus and pub/uk 
and also add below code.

```
location /aus {
    root /aus;
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /aus/index.php last;
        break;
    }
}
```

but my question is what i need to do when i point the domain ? how can i access this /aus and /uk folder and what i need to change ?

Any idea please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `map` and pass `MAGE_RUN_TYPE`, `MAGE_RUN_CODE` to `fastcgi_param`.

Here is an example:

```
map $http_host $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
  default '';
  dev.uk uk;
  dev.aus aus;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  servername dev.com dev.uk dev.aus;

  ....

  set $MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;

  ....

  location ~ \.php$ {
    ...

    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_TYPE $MAGE_RUN_TYPE;
    fastcgi_param MAGE_RUN_CODE $MAGE_RUN_CODE;

    ...
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: so is there also need to update this pub/aus and pub/uk folder location ?
means how to identify which folder need to execute when call to dev.uk ?

Comment: no, Magento bootstrap will do it. All you need to do is just deploy static content for each store view with its language used. For example: `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB`

Comment: is there need to setup virtual host for this new domain ?

Comment: your answer correct. Its working :)